# WPF 3D x-coordinate appears backwards

Tags: wpf, 3d

Using WPF 3D, I define my geometry as follows:

```
<MeshGeometry3D Positions="0 0 0  1 1 0  1 0 0" />
```

My camera is defined as

```
<PerspectiveCamera FarPlaneDistance="20" 
                    LookDirection="0,0,1" 
                    UpDirection="0,1,0" 
                    NearPlaneDistance="0" 
                    Position="0,0,-10" 
                    FieldOfView="45" />
```

However, when I look at the resulting picture, I get this:

[image: illustration]

It would appear that the X co-ordinate is backwards, i.e., the X axis is facing left. Curiously, when I try to flip the sign, i.e., when I write

```
<MeshGeometry3D Positions="0 0 0  -1 1 0  -1 0 0" />
```

The image disappears entirely. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your second question first...3d engines like WPF usually employ backface culling, where faces that point away from the camera aren't rendered in order to improve performance. You can fix this by either changing the order of the points in your `MeshGeometry3D` or assigning a `BackMaterial` to your `GeometryModel3D` (as opposed to the regular `Material`).

With respect to your first question, it's not the X that's flipped around, it's the Z. If you look at [the WPF 3D Graphics Overview on the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview) you'll see that Z is negative going into the screen. You've set your camera at [0,0,-10] and set the look direction to [0,0,1], so the camera is effectively "behind" the object and looking backwards. Change these values to [0,0,10] and [0,0,-1], and add a BackMaterial like I mentioned above, and all will be good in the world again.